# grails FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.Execution failed fro task ':boot run'

Tags: web-services, grails, build, ggts

got this error while I tried to run my very first grail app..:(
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFKfk.png)got this error while I tried to run my very first grail app..:(

Comment: please include your code

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code / commands / input / output as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some steps you can follow to resolve...

1. Check the JDK and Grails, both need to be same 32 bit or both need to be same 64 bit
2. Execute this on command prompt: `java -Xmx2048m -Xms256m`
3. Then rebuild and run app

Answer (score 0):

The initial memory allocated to your JVM is bigger than the maximum JVM memory size you allocated via your -Xmx parameter.

see [What are the Xms and Xmx parameters when starting JVMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms)